# Time lapse, adding yeast a week late

Tags: fermentation, yeast

After getting my grape juice in a bucket, I added the sugar and wild yeast killer. Didn't have the yeast to add before sealing it up. Checked the next day, it has a purple foam that collected on top. It's been a week, I should be getting my yeast in the next day or two.  The bubbler(airlock) on top bubbles at least once a minute.

Should I skim the foam that might still be collected top of juice?

Or stir it in when I add the yeast tomorrow?

Comment: Just before adding your yeast, it would be good to take a gravity measure with an hydrometer, so you know how much sugar was already fermented with the wild yeast (or how much is left).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't skim anything.  That just feels like it's more likely to cause a contamination.  If there still is wild yeast in there doing something skimming won't really change that, you just want to dump a pile of active yeast in to 'beat' the wild yeast to the food.

Comment: Indeed, there is no need to skim the foam.